# Simulating a mouse-click in jQuery

Tags: jquery

The following snippet displays a text table when clicked. I want the text table to display when the page is opened, by default, as if it were clicked. I'm a total newbie, this seems simple but I've tried dozens of alternatives without any luck - please help me.

```
//Show/Hide 'Text Alert' Table
jQuery('#showAlertTable').on('click', function () {
    jQuery('.alert-table').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: `$('#showAlertTable').click()`

Comment: The jQuery documentation is fantastic, I'd suggest you at least glance through it to get a vague idea of what can be achieved. Most method names are pretty self explanatory, for example http://api.jquery.com/click

Comment: Honestly, I've been on that site all day trying every variable to get this action to self-trigger, but I have to accept that my tiny brain does not grasp code. I need a fix for this like yesterday, and unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't work either.

Comment: @DeanP Don't depreciate your own ability, and this isn't really a matter of understanding code. A significant part of programming is learning how to best take advantage of the resources at your disposal. Searching through resources may take time to learn, but doing so will benefit you well beyond programming.

Comment: Do any of these answers fit your needs? If so you can accept that answer, If not, please comment on the answer to say what else you need.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to trigger it on ready without a click event:

```
$(function(){
    $('.alert-table').slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Genius! This works! At first it did not because I applied it after the $('#showAlertTable') entry. Once I removed that, it works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For doing things once the page has loaded, you should take a look at jquery's `$(document).ready(...)` function. The documentation can be found [on jquery's website](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

In your case, we will take the callback for your click handler, and pull that out as a separate function, so that we can trigger it both on click, and on page load like so.

**Edited** to reflect more flexible syntax.

```
function showTable(){
    jQuery('.alert-table').slideToggle();
}

// add click handler
jQuery('#showAlertTable').on('click', showTable);

// fires showTable as soon as the document is ready,
// or right away if the document is already ready. 
jQuery(showTable);
```

Comment: Since jQuery 3.0 you should only use `jQuery( showTable )`/`$( showTable )` because all other syntaxes are deprecated. And even if not the `jQuery('document')` is one of worst syntaxes, because `jQuery('document') looks like you query for an element with the tag name `document` and then attach a ready event callback to it.

Comment: That is precisely what jquery is doing. This is shorthand for `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)`

Comment: At the time I wrote the comment it was `jQuery('document')` and this was the worst solution. Anyway my point is still true: see [`Deprecated: document-ready handlers other than jQuery(function)`](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#deprecated-document-ready-handlers-other-than-jquery-function). Beside that the ready callback is not a just shorthand  for `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ...)` because using `$(function)` will delay the callback until the DOM is ready or call it immediately if it is already ready.

Comment: sorry, i understand your comment better now. I have updated the answer to reflect the better syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Triggering the `click` event after binding the handler should do it. This is a common pattern:

```
jQuery('#showAlertTable').on('click', function () {
    jQuery('.alert-table').slideToggle();
}).click();
```